# Open EditTextPreference whenever the AlertDialog is clicked

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, preferences, live-wallpaper

I have the PreferenceScreen list with

CheckBoxPreference
     and
EditTextPreference

My goal is whenever the CheckBoxPreference is checked, it opens up the AlertDialog options: OK or Cancel.  If the "OK" is clicked, it is supposed to open up the 
EditTextPreference to enter the password.

I've been looking online and tried a lot of different ways, but I can't seem to
find a way to open up the EditTextPreference.

Could someone please help me out?

This is for the live wallpaper settings....

Thank you.

Codes:

```
    if(key.equals("checkbox")) {        
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Please Login For Privacy");
        builder.setPositiveButton("       Login      ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


   CheckBoxPreference mcheckbox2 = (CheckBoxPreference)   
   findPreference("checkbox");
   EditTextPreference editbox = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("login");

   mcheckbox2.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
   public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
   if(newValue.toString().equals("false")) {
        prefs.this.editbox.setEnabled(false);
    } else if(newValue.toString().equals("true")) {
        prefs.this.editbox.setEnabled(true);
    }
    return true;
```

Notice:

```
prefs.this.editbox.setEnabled(false);
```

or

```
prefs.this.editbox.setEnabled(true);
```

give me error.  It won't let me run the app :-(

Comment: Please add your code that you tried

Comment: If you have googled you can find many ways to solve your problem. Use correct Tag to find your solution.

Comment: codes are added,  thank you very much

Comment: What error did you get? Can you show your logcat please?

Comment: It won't let me run the app because it has 2 errors: The method setEnabled(boolean) is undefined for the type Object  and  The method setEnabled(boolean) is undefined for the type Object

Comment: This is because that methods not applicable for `EditTextPreference`.

Comment: is there another way to accomplish my goal?  Thank you

Comment: Please someone.  I hope an expert can help me out.  This thing has haunting me for days.  Thank you